# Django ORM Query for Sum of positive and negative values Separately

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm

I have a column in a database, let's call it as dummy_column.
It has values both positive and negative.
I want to calculate the sum of all the positive numbers as well as the sum of all the negative numbers as well as the whole sum(positive+negative) i.e. I want the output in 3 separate values.

Calculating the sum of both can be done by using Sum('dummy_column')

Tried with Case and When, but can't understand what to put in the 'then' clause.

Saw this answer related, but I want to avoid the 'extra'. - '[Django queryset SUM positive and negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780041/django-queryset-sum-positive-and-negative-values)'

Wasn't much to write the code, so didn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

## Process with three aggregates

You can use a `Sum(..)` over a `Case` like:

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, IntegerField, Sum, Value, When

agg = SomeModel.objects.aggregate(
    total=Sum('value'),
    total_pos=Sum(Case(
        When(value__gt=0, then=F('value')),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )),
    total_neg=Sum(Case(
        When(value__lt=0, then=F('value')),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
)
```

(with `SomeModel` the model for which we want to calculate the aggregate, and `value` the field (here an `IntegerField`, that contains values we want to sum up).

The `When(..)` objects thus specify that we pass the `'value'` value for rows where `value__gt=0` (the value is greater than zero), or `value__lt=0` (the value is less than zero).

This will result in a dictionary with three keys, for example:

```
# sample output
agg == {'total': 12, 'total_pos': 14, 'total_neg': -2}
```

You can then thus fetch the values like:

```
agg['total']  # 12
```

## Process with two aggregates

Since we know however that `agg['total'] == agg['total_pos'] + agg['total_neg']`, we can only calculate *one* of the elements, and post process the dictionary, like:

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, IntegerField, Sum, Value, When

agg = SomeModel.objects.aggregate(
    total=Sum('value'),
    total_pos=Sum(Case(
        When(value__gt=0, then=F('value')),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ))
)

agg['total_neg'] = agg['total'] - agg['total_pos']
```

This might be more efficient, since we avoid inspecting each row an extra time (although this depends on how the database does indexing, etc.).

Comment: Your code is missing some commas.... and I couldn't get the output_field to be acceptable?

agg = SomeModel.objects.aggregate(
    total=Sum('value'),
    total_pos=Sum(Case(
        When(value__gt=0, then=F('value')),
        default=Value(0)
    ))
)

Comment: @BenjaminSchollnick: thanks, I've added the comma's. What field are you using for `value` in your case?

Comment: I'm using a field called display_size, where it's the size of a file.. (with -1 representing non-existent). So thus, only wanting to sum positive values...

display_size = models.BigIntegerField(default=-1, db_index = True)